# Removing the first element in a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function which removes an element in a linked list. I'm only having trouble with removing the head of the list. I'm able to remove any other element just fine. Here's my code (I only included the part of the function which deals with deleting the head).

```
template <class T>
void SinglyLinkedList<T>::remove(std::size_t i) {
     //i is the element to be deleted

     SinglyLinkedListNode *p=head;

     // checks if the size is 0 or if the node isn't in the list
     if( size()==0 && i>=size())
         return;

    //check if first element
    if(i==0){
       head=head->next;
      //delete p;
   }
}
```

My problem is with freeing the memory (I commented out the deleting here). When I comment it out like I am now it works fine (but obviously results in a memory leak) but when I uncomment it I get a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I'm sorry, I forgot to include the rest of my code: Here's the implementation:

```
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

// Nested class representing the nodes in the list.
class SinglyLinkedListNode {
public:
    // The value stored in this node.
    T value;

    // The next node in the sequence.
    SinglyLinkedListNode *next;

    SinglyLinkedListNode(T value) :
        value(value), next(nullptr) {}

    SinglyLinkedListNode(T v, SinglyLinkedListNode *n) :
        value(v), next(n) {}

    // Return the size (length) of the linked list.
    std::size_t size();
};

SinglyLinkedListNode *head;
SinglyLinkedListNode *tail;

public:
// Constructs a new SinglyLinkedList from an initializer_list of type T[].
// This is mostly for convenience, especially when testing.

SinglyLinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> items): head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)                
{   
    if (items.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // initializer_lists were designed to be used iteratively,
    // so thats what we do.
    auto it = items.begin();
    while (it != items.end()) {
        this->push_back(*it++);
    }
}

T* at(std::size_t i);
void push_back(T value);
void push_front(T value);
std::size_t size();
void remove(std::size_t i);
void insert(std::size_t i, T value);
void append(SinglyLinkedList<T> list);
```

So I'm creating a linked list using an initializer list and then trying to remove that element. But it's failing

```
SinglyLinkedList<int> lst = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
lst.remove(0);
```

Update 2: By request here's my push_back function

```
template <class T>
void SinglyLinkedList<T>::push_back(T value) {

  //when empty
  if(head==nullptr){
    head= new SinglyLinkedListNode(value);
    tail=head;
  }
  //when not empty
  else{
    tail->next= new SinglyLinkedListNode(value);
    tail= tail->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Too minimal. We have no idea how you are storing and linking and can't answer the question. Minimal and complete, please. (Produce a [mcve])

Comment: Just because a program crashes on a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Your bug can be anywhere in your program which is, as you've been advised, a [mcve] is needed. Note that the "Minimal" part of does not mean "dumping your entire source code into a question". You need to show the absolute minimum required to reproduce the bug.

Comment: I would suggest looking at some other implementations of linked lists in C++ and making sure you understand them. I haven't tested this one but you could give it a shot. http://pumpkinprogrammer.com/2014/06/13/c-tutorial-intro-to-linked-lists/. If that link doesn't work, this is a pretty common data structure and you can find thousands of working code samples on line.

Comment: Could you show your push back function?

Comment: Did you really check the content of your list after removing another item than the first one ? Because when looking on the `remove()` function, your are doing nothing except for `( i==0)`.

Comment: As Stated above I didn't include that part of the remove function because it was working fine (I checked after removing and it was fine). The only problem is with freeing the memory of the original head.